# What is the user's username?

Tags: django, django-models

In one of my Django models, I override the save function. I do this to get the user's username. But that keeps failing.

this is what i did:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify('%s' % (self.question))
    if not self.id:
        self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.publisher = self.request.user
    self.modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.modifier = self.request.user
    super(Faq, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method
```

This fails with:
'Faq' object has no attribute 'request'

Thanks.

Comment: plase, publish the complete Model class.

Comment: The code as posted would not raise that error, since you are not referencing a global `request` anywhere there. So, either that isn't the code that you're actually using, or the traceback actually refers to a different bit of code.

Comment: Sorry. This is the original code. I copied this and then thought to make a change by removing 'self.' I did that and reloaded the page which then returned that error.

Comment: I've updated the post with the 'correct' error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for use within the Admin app, as you say in your answer to Jake, then you shouldn't override the model save method at all. Instead, you should override the `save_model` method of the `ModelAdmin` class.

See the original code in `django.contrib.admin.options` - you'll see that it's already passed the `request` object. So all you need to do is to assign the `publisher` there:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.slug = slugify('%s' % (obj.question))
    if not obj.id:
        obj.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        obj.publisher = request.user
    obj.modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    obj.modifier = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, for pointing this out! :) And, for providing the solution. Just for my understanding, save_model method at the end calls. obj.save(). That call to save is the one that is specified in model.py. Yes? 

Thanks to everybody who responded. :)

Comment: Actually, I went ahead and tested it... In save_model override, I just have the line obj.save(request) and the save override in models.py I changed from self.request.user to request.user. This worked nicely. So, should I ever save from a view, I will have the functionality that I want. :)  Again, thanks.

Comment: Great, Jake, thanks for the suggestion. Clearly a better solution than what I had. :)

Answer (score 1):

`request` is only passed to views, not model methods so you will have to set the `publisher` in a view.

I would remove the line `self.modifier = self.request.user` from here and set `modifier = request.user` at the same time as you set `question` which I assume you are doing in a view.

Then you can change `self.publisher = self.request.user` to `self.publisher = self.modifier`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jake. The problem there is that this is from the Admin section.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the request into the save method since it doesn't exist in that context automatically.

```
def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify('%s' % (self.question))
    if not self.id:
        self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.publisher = request.user
    self.modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.modifier = self.request.user
    super(Faq, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method
```

Usage...

```
my_faq = Faq()
my_faq.save(request)
```

Comment: Adam, this is done from the Admin section. So, I don't think I have the option to send the request along with the call.